# sql left join: always return left table columns, no matter the condition

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-design

I've got two tables:

#### account_settings

This table uses the settings.id field as an FK to store the users custom settings (the settings table below has the name of the setting and the default value)

```
    Column    |           Type           |                           Modifiers
--------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                  | not null default nextval('account_settings_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id      | uuid                     | not null
 setting_id   | integer                  | not null
 value        | text                     |
```

#### settings:

This table holds all the available settings. E.g weekly_email, app_notifications, block_user, etc...It also holds the default value for each of them.

```
     Column     |           Type           |                       Modifiers
----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('settings_id_seq'::regclass)
 key            | text                     | not null
 frontend_label | text                     |
 default_value  | text                     |
```

I'm using the property bag schema design to store user settings for our app! It will include notification settings, email settings, etc...

Is it possible to have a query that always returns the `settings` columns, even when you add a where statement in there (the where statement is there for querying for the account_settings by user_id)?

I'm trying to get an accounts customs settings, as well as the LEFT JOIN the `settings` table for the default values & labels.

Here is what I have now:

```
select account_settings.*, settings.* from settings 
LEFT JOIN account_settings 
ON settings.id = account_settings.id 
where account_settings.user_id = 'UUID_HERE';
```

This won't return the the settings table values though! It will only return the settings values if the settings.id column is referenced in the account_settings.setting_id column.

Comment: An `integer` is not a `UUID`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove your where condition put it with join on condition

```
 select account_settings.*, settings.* from settings 
    LEFT JOIN account_settings 
    ON settings.id = account_settings.id and account_settings.user_id = 'UUID_HERE';
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!! Would you happen to know if this would be expensive at scale? E.g if there were millions of records in the account_settings table

Comment: @James111 sorry i have no idea about it